# How to Integrate OutSystems to MuleSoft?

Tags: mule, middleware, outsystems, eai

I need to integrate **Mulesoft** with **OutSystems**. Can anyone help me in knowing the basics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As **OutSystems** and and **Mulesoft** both can consume and produce REST as well as SOAP API. You can integrate Mulesoft using any of these web services

You can refer [OutSystems article](https://success.outsystems.com/Evaluation/Integration/00_Integrate_with_SOAP_web_services_and_REST_APIs)  and for [Mulesoft documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To Add to AnupamBhusari answer.
You also need to define how you're going to implement the authorization.
Either use API keys that you can send to Mulesoft as REST parameters or Headers or make use of long lived OAuth2 tokens.

You also need to consider how to implement versioning of the consumed API and have a good architecture that decouples the changes in the MuleSoft exposed API. Check the external Core Service pattern described in this [link](https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Enterprise_Customers/Maintenance_and_Operations/Designing_the_architecture_of_your_OutSystems_applications/05_Service_architecture_patterns/01_Core_Service_abstraction).